# Cauchy Riemann equations to solve $u(x,y) = e^{x^2 - y^2}\cos(2xy)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have applied the equations to get 
$$\frac{{\partial}u}{{\partial}x}= 2xe^{x^2 - y^2}\cos(2xy) - 2ye^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy) = \frac{{\partial}v}{{\partial}y}$$

Unsure of how to integrate that quantity for v?

Comment: Not clear what the question is.  How do you "solve" a formula for a function?  Are you trying to see whether $u(x,y)$ is holomoprhic?

Comment: maybe is useful to note that $u(x,y)=Re(e^{(x+iy)^{2}})$

Comment: I suspect the OP is trying to find $v$ such that $u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ is a holomorphic function of $z = x+iy$.

Comment: Why should $\frac{\partial v }{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$? Don't you mean $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ assuming the complex valued function is $u+vi$?

Comment: @mathreadler yes i meant the latter

Comment: Then as you say, what remains is to try and integrate the expression wrt $y$ (assuming you calculated the expression right). Maybe you can be helped with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: @mathreadler I'm unsure of how to do this since I would use by parts with an exponential and cos; wouldn't i keep getting something that doesn't simplify to give an integrable expression?

Comment: Eulers formula $\exp(ix) = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ can maybe together with exponential laws help you simplify the expression.

Comment: @mathreadler there are no i's in the expression

Comment: There are i's everywhere. Maybe you just don't see them.

Comment: I did it through integration by visualisation.